# How to find the value of input field using jquery .closest() method when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, closest

This code is giving me undefined value when I try to show the value through alert message.

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">   
  <div class="aid_closest"> 
       <input type="text" name="aid" id="aid" class="aid" value="sample_value"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I put inside my script code..

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  var aid = $(this).closest("div.aid_closest").find("input[name='aid']").val();
  
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    alert(aid);
  }
});
</script>
```

I'd appreciate all the help and suggestion you will give to me.

Comment: `closest` checks the element itself, and then proceeds with its ancestors. Your checkbox input does not have the class `aid_closest`, and neither does it have an ancestor with that class.

Comment: (And please tag appropriately. In its current form, this has absolutely nothing to do with `php`. Tag removed.)

Comment: Just a word of warning when selecting elements by their position; layouts can change, and if you move things around in the HTML, you will need to update all JS you have that references the elements by their old position. That could make a quick design change break things, taking a lot longer to fix (and possibly create bugs you miss when changing). A safer way would be to give elements you need to identify some `id`'s or similar and use that to select. You can even use the `data`-attribute to tell which element id it belongs to, so you fetch that value and fetch the elements that way.

Comment: I thank you all for your comments and suggestions. I'll definitely consider all the things you've said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `next` jQuery function.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
   var aid = $(this).next('.aid_closest').find("input[name='aid']").val();

   if($(this).is(":checked")){
       alert(aid);
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

.closest()

> testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

In you example

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox">   
 <div class="aid_closest"> 
   <input type="text" name="aid" id="aid" class="aid" value="sample_value"> 
 </div>
</div>
```

you can change

```
var aid = $(this).closest("div.aid_closest").find("input[name='aid']").val();
```

to

```
var aid = $(this).closest("div").find("input[name='aid']").val();
```